# Does Compiling one csproj with MSBuild Compile referenced projects as well?

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration

My question is pretty simple. Do I have to do a complete solution compile with MSBuild if I have multiple projects that reference each other via project reference, or can I simply compile just one of my projects, say my web deployment project, and MSBuild will figure out the references, and compile the referenced projects for me?

I am trying to simplify our CI environment, and I find it strange that I am currently building the whole solution, then individual deployment projects separately.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try it before asking? What happened?

Comment: Damn, you caught me Jon, I was lazy and I have not tried it yet. I will though once I get some time to play with some test code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use msbuild to compile the solution if you want references to also be updated.  This also requires that the solution be setup with proper depedencies, and the projects be set to build (which typically happens by default).

Compiling a single .csproj will only compile that project.

Comment: Thank you! Basically my current CI system compiles the system (without deployment projects) and runs unit tests, if they pass, I then compile the deployment projects individually which will retrieve the dlls that were compiled in my original solution build.